# Parse an ASCII based CSV file so EXCEL will parse out tab'ed data?

Tags: excel, text, ascii

I am always getting requests to export data into a file for Excel. I work in an ASCII environment in Pick Database.

I would like to parse the text based csv so that when it's opened up in Excel, Excel would translate the parsing into separate tabs of data within the Excel document.

Comment: You would need to include some kind of marker in the file to indicate where one tab's data stops and the next tab's data begins. *(unless there are a fixed number of records for each tab)*

Comment: There is no concept of "Tabs" in a CSV file, and Excel has no mechanism to auto-parse some kind of marker you may include in your file, so without some type of macro in Excel this is not going to be possible.

Comment: See - Now that's something I can do and test.